# Making a retrofit call without using the Base URL, GET @Url annotation failing

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am building an app in Android and would like to make some calls with Retrofit.
I have an API class that makes the calls, I have one call that uses the base URL and then builds on top of the base URL, but the second call is given a customized URL so I do not want the base URL to be used.
I used a @GET annotation and declared my argument with @Url but when I look at the output it is still using the base URL and then concatenating the custom URL after it.

Here is my class:

```
import com.alimuzaffar.example.dogs.model.AlbumImages;
import com.alimuzaffar.example.dogs.model.DogBreeds;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Url;

public class Api {

    private static ApiInterface api;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://rss.itunes.apple.com";

    public static ApiInterface getApi() {
        if (api == null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .build();

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(
                            DogBreeds.class,
                            new JsonDogBreedsDeserializer()).setLenient()
                    .create();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

            api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        }
        return api;
    }

    public interface ApiInterface
    {
        @GET("api/v1/us/apple-music/top-albums/all/25/explicit.json/")
        Call<DogBreeds> getBreeds();

        @GET
        Call<AlbumImages> fetchImage(@Url String url);
    }
}
```

Comment: For that you need to create seperate retrofit instance.can not use same instance.

Comment: Hey Thank you for your comment, I tried that, unfortunately, retrofit is forcing me to provide it with a valid, non-empty base URL. But my URLs are all custom and do not even have a common base. Once I declare the new instance, how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to one persons' comment, I created a brand new instance of retrofit and gave my custom URL as the base URL

```
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(
                    DogBreeds.class,
                    new JsonDogBreedsDeserializer()).setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(this.getImageUrl())
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    ApiInterfaceImage api = retrofit.create(ApiInterfaceImage.class);
    api.fetchImage().enqueue(callback);
```